# give copied items in listbox an ID

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Write now i can Copy items over between 2 listboxes. The problem is that when i copy the same items from listbox1 to listbox2 there is no problem, but when i delete the last item in listbox 2 it will
delete all the others items before the last items because it is the same object. So i need to give my copied items and ID so when i copy an items over to listbox2 it will not be the same as the next item that will be copied to listbox2..

```
private void CopyItemOver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (ElementControl item in ElementListBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                if (item == null)
                    return;
                else
                {
                    SequenceListBox.ValueMember = item.ID.ToString();
                    item.ID++;
                    SequenceListBox.Items.Add(item);
                    elementNumber++;

                }
                SequenceListBox.SelectedIndex = SequenceListBox.Items.Count - 1;
                SequenceListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                Update();

            }
            if (ElementListBox.SelectedItems.Count <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var objElement = SequenceListBox.Items[itemCounter] as ElementControl;
                if (SequenceListBox.Items.Count == 1)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] { ElementListBox.SelectedItems.Count.ToString() + "  Elements moved to SequenceListBox", "Ready", GetTime() + "  " + elementNumber});
                    LogListView.Items.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { ElementListBox.SelectedItems.Count.ToString() + "  Elements moved to SequenceListBox", "Ready", GetTime() + "  " + elementNumber });
                    LogListView.Items.Add(item1);
                }
            }
            LogListView.Items[LogListView.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
        }
```

Hope to make my question clear enough.

DuMaSexy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
SequenceListBox.Items.Add(item);
```

use:

```
SequenceListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = item.Text, Value = item.Value);
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' does not contain a definition for 'Value'

Comment: are you sure it is ListItem and not ListViewItem?

Comment: i dont got this ListItem function. i'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5 as well and My `ListBox` control has a `ListItemCollection` with `Add` method that  exposes: `void ListItemCollection(ListItem item)`. Inherited from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl` `public virtual ListItemCollection Items { get; }`. Why does your `ListBox` use `ListViewItem`, are you by any chance using `ListView` instead of `ListBox`?

Comment: i'm working in windows form. maybe that's why i dont have that? cant add reference System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl

Comment: I fixed it.. I was force to make a deep copy, so everytime i copied an item over til an other listbox i gave them an ID so i could copy the same item more than 1 time. The object has the same values but they have differnce ID. Hf DuMaSexy